# How to merge versioned files using Git?

Tags: git, github

I'm using Versioncake in my web app, Github as a source control platform, and having some troubles with handling a merge process for my versioned files.

Lets say I've made my changes on example.html file. In order to create a newer version I rename it to example.v2.html. Now, I've created a new file, named it after the 'older' version (In this case it will be example.html), and filled it with the latest code exists on my 'master' branch.
So, now I have the old, renamed file, and a new file with the content of the older version.

example.html - newly created file, holds content from 'master' branch.
example.v2.html - previously known as 'example.html'. It was renamed. Holds my latest version.

What is the best practice to merge my renamed 'example.v2.html' with his matching 'example.html' from master branch?

In case I'm doing it all wrong:
What is the best practice to handle versioned files in my app?

Comment: Yes, that's basically all wrong. Since changing and committing files are the most basic operations I strongly suggest you read a bit in [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). At the very least the first two chapters.

Comment: Guys,
I have to versions of the same file. The two of them are in use. How do you manage to handle it ?

Comment: You modify the file in place. The two versions don't exist at the same time in the file system. That's the very reason you use a VCS. Give Pro Git a read. It's an excellent introduction that got me started in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't understand the concept of GIT. You should make new branches instead if renaming your files.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/

First you should read how branches work and how you can commit something to your new branch. On the left on my link you can see how to checkout and merge.